# Reusing a fragment controller of Sapui5 in other applications

Tags: sapui5

I am developing multiple applications and there are same areas within these applications. And these fields contain the same f4 search help. But I want to write it in a single application and reuse it in other applications, not separately for every application. But my applications are Standalone applications, not Launchpad applications. What is the best method for this?
I've found that I can't use Standalone apps this way on some sources. Is this true?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SAPUI5 - reuse fragments across multiple applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47794727/sapui5-reuse-fragments-across-multiple-applications)

Comment: Yes, but the answer is not clear enough for me.

Comment: "I've found that I can't use Standalone apps this way on some sources" - WHERE DO YOU FOUND THIS?

Comment: This is one of the answers I got to the question I asked in a different community:

"You can explore this possibility. But the fact that you are deploying a standalone application defies this purpose."-Reddit